# Android Studio Dependencies Error with google play services API

Tags: android-studio

(mixing version can lead to run time crashes). How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to describe what you are trying to do and precisely why it does not work?

Comment: I was testing to convert a website into an Android app and trying to add interstitial AdMob ad.